# angularjs 1.x - stateProvider ignoring url property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with a main state and a child state. I do have the url property set but it seems angular it is ignoring it, but it is not ignoring the optional parameter at the end, which is correctly populated. Please see below code snippet. (to be honest, this application always worked but after an update in the Siemens product this particular feature is not behaving correctly, but at the end of the day this is an angular app, so I am not sure how they could have changed globally this behavior if you have an idea I will be very happy to check that). thanks

this is the main page:

```
 function config($stateProvider) {
    var item = {
        name: "Carriers",
        //ShippingAndReceiving is ignored, but /:direction is correclty attached to the URL
        url: '/ShippingAndReceiving/:direction', 
        views: {
            'Canvas@': {
                templateUrl: folder + '/carrierOverview.html',
                controller: 'CarrierOverviewController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Vehicles'
        },
        params: {
            reload: null,
            carrier: null,
            direction: null,
            arriving: null
        }
    };

    $stateProvider.state(item);
   }
```

this is the child page:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    var item = {
        name: 'Carriers.Details',
        url: '/RegisterVehicle',
    };

    $stateProvider.state(item);
  }
```

both the pages load correctly and everything works properly, but the URL does not change, it is constantly "Carriers" for both pages.

I do not have any extra unnecessary $state.go anywhere.

this is the call to browse to the page:

```
$state.go('Carriers.Details');
```